# server.urlencode does not encode special characters

Tags: asp-classic

I have a piece of code that redirects to a page using `server.urlEncode (fields)` when the captcha isn't entered correctly. Code looks like:

```
sRedirectTo = "page.asp" _
& "?action=vcerr" _
& "&at=" & server.urlEncode(sAdType) _
& "&fn=" & server.urlEncode(sFirstname) _
& "&mn=" & server.urlEncode(sMiddleName) _
& "&ln=" & server.urlEncode(sLastName) _
& "&sx=" & server.urlEncode(sSex) _
& "&pr=" & server.urlEncode(sProvince) _
& "&cn=" & server.urlEncode(sCountry) _
& "&cy=" & server.urlEncode(sCity) _
& "&md=" & server.urlEncode(dMomentDate) _
& "&ag=" & server.urlEncode(iAgree) _
& "&chn=" & server.urlEncode(sCharityName) _
& "&chu=" & server.urlEncode(sCharityUrl) _
& "&city=" & server.urlEncode(sCityID) _
& "&key=" & server.urlEncode(sKeywords)
```

However, when the `cy` entry is for a city like Saint-Jérome, it fails encode the accent. Url in browser bar looks like this:
page.asp?action=vcerr[...]&cy=SAINT-JÉRÔME&od=10%2F05%2[...]

Then the text is pulled using `QueryString("cy)` and displayed on the page, causing the characters to not be displayed correctly.

Is there something I'm missing here? I'm unsure of why `server.urlEncode` doesn't work.

EDIT:

I checked the variable `sRedirectTo` while debugging, it seems that the `urlEncode` does work on the characters, so the switch happens between the `Response.redirect` and the `QueryString`. Is it possible that the redirect removed the encoding for the special characters? Also what's strange is that the urlencoding done on the other variables stays intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've set your `CodePage` and `Charset` to `UTF-8` and saved both files in `UTF-8`.

Testing scripts I used:

**`r.asp`**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"

cy = "SAINT-JÉRÔME"
Response.Redirect("p.asp?cy=" & cy)
%>
```

**`p.asp`**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"

cy = Request.QueryString("cy")

Response.Write cy
%>
```

**Output:**

```
SAINT-JÉRÔME
```

Comment: What would happen if instead of containing "SAINT-JÉRÔME" the `cy` variable was assigned "Hello&oops=World"?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Since my example script doesn't use `Server.URLEncode`, the output would be "Hello".